# Describe the graph of $f^{-1}$ when $f$ is decreasing and always negative - dispute with solution from Spivak.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, inverse-function

The question comes from *Calculus by Spivak - Ch 12 - 2) iv)*. It asks us to describe the graph of $f^{-1}$ when $f$ is decreasing and always negative. I interpret the inverse function as decreasing and not defining it for $x \geq 0$. But using the tools I have at my disposal, mainly the diagonal line test and drawings, I would get a function  that is increasing but still defined only on for $x < 0$. This is also what the solution manual says: here is a screenshot of its solution.

[image]

I really don't agree with the drawing of the inverse function. I agree with how the original function, $f$, is drawn. Based on the tools this is correct, but it feels wrong......What may I be missing to reconcile this somewhat simple issue?

Comment: You are right.  The inverse of a decreasing function is another decreasing function.  In fact, the text says $f^{-1}$ is decreasing.  But the picture shows $f^{-1}$ increasing.

Answer (score 3):

You are right, the graph of $f^{-1}$ is incorrect: I think that the graph of $f$ was rotated 90 degrees clockwise instead of being flipped with respect to the line $y=x$. It should diverge to $-\infty$ as $x\to \alpha^-=\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)$, and diverge to $\infty$ as $x\to\beta=\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$. Here, from the graph of $f$, it seems that $\alpha=0$ and $\beta=-\infty$, but this is not part of the hypothesis, strictly speaking.

Comment: Good. At least I know I'm not beating myself up for nothing, but that means I applied the diagonal line procedure wrong because I got the incorrect reflection  (i got the one above instead of the correct one).....time to refine my application of the diagonal criterion

Comment: just adding to this answer: here's an example of what it [could look like](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/s4wia5ocpe) (I put $f(x)=-e^{x}$, $x\in \Bbb{R}$ and $f^{-1}(y) = \ln(-y)$, $y>0$)